# rate per series in Prometheus

Tags: grafana, rate, prometheus

I use

```
{__name__=~"outgoing_requests_.*_timer_count"}
```

which results in several series like

```
outgoing_requests_host1_timer_count
outgoing_requests_host2_timer_count
outgoing_requests_host3_timer_count
```

for each of those, I'd like to use `rate()` and display them on the same graph. But use `rate` seems to aggregate all of them into on big rate

How do I `rate` on each series

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you don't know your metric names in advance due to having the instance in the the metric name rather than in a label. You can extract these via metric relabelling: https://www.robustperception.io/extracting-labels-from-legacy-metric-names/

Comment: See [demo robust perception](http://demo.robustperception.io:9090/graph?g0.range_input=1h&g0.stacked=0&g0.expr=rate(%7B__name__%3D~%22node_memory_.*%22%7D%5B1m%5D)&g0.tab=0) where the regex matches a lot of metrics, but the resulting plot is just one. So I'd like to get the rate of each of the matching series